# Wordpress fountainpress header is covering top bar

Tags: menus, headers

I changed wordpress menu from admin panel and now is some part of menu behind header.
How can I space out certain part of menu or move header little bit up?

Comment: This is a problem with your theme. Its developer should know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is a conflict between your theme's css and the admin header.  Options are to modify your theme's css, or remove the admin bar.

To remove your admin bar add this to your theme's functions.php file:
    add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');